# What's the reading order for "Red daughter of krypton" (2014)?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, supergirl, crossovers

I've looked around the net, but can't find anything concrete.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the reviewer on [readingorders.com](http://www.readingorders.com/ReadingOrderList/RedDaughterOfKrypton), if you stick with...

> - Red Lanterns 27: Hot and Cold 01 March 2014
> - Supergirl 28: Rage Quit 01 April 2014
> - Supergirl 29: Red Daughter of Krypton: Part 1: Inner Demons 01 May 2014
> - Green Lantern 28: Red Alert: Part 1 01 April 2014
> - Red Lanterns 28: Red Alert: Part 2 01 April 2014
> - Red Lanterns 29: Forever 01 May 2014
> - Supergirl 30: Red Daughter of Krypton: Part 2: Red Remembrance 01 June 2014
> - Red Lanterns 30: Judgement Day: Part 1 01 June 2014
> - Supergirl 31: Red Daughter of Krypton: Part 3: Judgement Day
> - Red Lanterns 31: Judgement Day: Part 3
> - Red Lanterns 32: Atrocities: Part 1: Cry Havoc 01 August 2014
> - Supergirl 32: Red Daughter of Krypton: Part 4: Homecoming 01 August 2014
> - Supergirl 33: Red Daughter of Krypton: Conclusion

...then you should avoid any major spoilers which still preserving most of the chronology.